# Mongo search regex ignore puntuation

Tags: regex, mongodb

It`s possible to create one regex in mongo search to ignore puntuation ?

I have in my collection something like

```
123.456.789-01

or

33.018.843/09881-20
```

So if I look for some 123456 (I want to find the first or more)
and if I found for 8430 (I need to find the second or more)

I want to ignore the puntuation and when that string are.

tks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Are you aware of the `$options` operator that goes with `$regex`?

`$options: "x"` will help you overcome this.

Comment: But "x" will ignoer only whitespace accord with doc.: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure it is possible via regex. However, there's a workaround, look this:

given the following colletion:

```
> db.teste.find() 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57f65bc8b9b3f8a0acacc0c1"),
    "num": "33.018.843/09]881-20"
} 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57f65bcbb9b3f8a0acacc0c2"),
    "num": "123.456.789-01"
}
```

So:

```
db.teste.find().map(function(doc) {
    var str = doc.num.replace(/[./\-]/g, "");
    if (str.indexOf("8430") > -1) return (doc);
}).filter(function(e, i) {
    if (e) return e;
});
```

I don't know what you are doing neither what are your needs but I hope it be helpful.